# Load JSON from s3 inside aws glue pyspark job

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to retrieve a JSON file from an s3 bucket inside a glue pyspark script.

I am running this function in the job inside aws glue:

```
def run(spark):
    s3_bucket_path = 's3://bucket/data/file.gz'

    df = spark.read.json(s3_bucket_path)
    df.show()
```

After this I am getting:
AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: s3://bucket/data/file.gz;'

I searched for this issue and did not find anything that would be similar enough to infer where is the issue. I think there might be permission issues accessing the bucket, but then the error message should be different.

Comment: You should make sure that the URL is publicly accessible. If you don't explicitly make it public, it won't be accessible via that URL, even if you are an authorized user.

Answer (score 8):

Here You can Try This :

```
    s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-west-2", aws_access_key_id=" 
        ", aws_secret_access_key="")
    jsonFile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile["Body"])
```

where `Key` = `full path to your file in bucket`

and use this  `jsonObject` in `spark.read.json(jsonObject)`